# How correctly to group array in md-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to group array in md-select? in my example is not working now [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/DJ5Aqe0oRxCYByqEsxyz?p=preview)

any idea how to do this correctly??

app.ts

```
export class SelectFormExample {
      selectedValue: string = 'Steak';

      foodsanddrinks = [
        {group: 'food', viewValue: 'Steak'},
        {group: 'food', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
        {group: 'food', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
        {group: 'drink', viewValue: 'Pepsi'},
        {group: 'drink', viewValue: 'Coca-cola'},
        {group: 'drink', viewValue: 'Fanta'}
      ];
    }
```

html

```
  <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">

    <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10px">Food</div>
    <md-option *ngFor="let fooddrink of foodsanddrinks" [value]="fooddrink.viewValue">
      <div *ngIf="fooddrink.group === 'food'">{{fooddrink.viewValue}}</div>
    </md-option>

    <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10px">Drink</div>
    <md-option *ngFor="let fooddrink of foodsanddrinks" [value]="fooddrink.viewValue">
      <div *ngIf="fooddrink.group === 'drink'">{{fooddrink.viewValue}}</div>
    </md-option>

  </md-select>

  <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following Pipe,

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'menuGrouping',
  pure: false
})
export class MenuGrouping implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
    if (items !== undefined) {
      return items.filter(item => {
        for (let field in conditions) {
          if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and in **`template`**

```
<md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10px">Food</div>
  <md-option *ngFor="let fooddrink of foodsanddrinks | menuGrouping:{group:'food'}" [value]="fooddrink.viewValue">
    {{fooddrink.viewValue}}
  </md-option>
  <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10px">Drink</div>
  <md-option *ngFor="let fooddrink of foodsanddrinks | menuGrouping:{group:'drink'}" [value]="fooddrink.viewValue">
    {{fooddrink.viewValue}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xIHcWkARdN2MTNf5gQUP?p=preview)**

Comment: Any reason to make this pipe **impure**?

Answer (score 0):

Since [**Material2#Beta.7**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta7-glass-delicatessen-2017-06-19) you can use `md-optgroup` *component*.

Below you can see the required steps:

First of all you have to group your items... you can create a function like this:

```
groupBy(arr, prop): any {
  const result = arr.reduce((grouped, item) => {
    const key = item[prop];
    grouped[key] = grouped[key] || [];
    grouped[key].push(item);

    return grouped;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(result).map(key => {
    return {
      key,
      values: result[key]
    };
  });
}
```

*Calling* it:

```
this.grouppedArray = this.groupBy(this.foodsanddrinks, 'group');
```

Now, the values will be transformed to:

```
[
  {
    key: 'food'
    values: // array with the food content
  },
  {
    key: 'drink'
    values: // array with the drink content
  }
]
```

Now, in template:

```
<md-select placeholder="Foods and Drinks" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <md-optgroup *ngFor="let optGroup of grouppedArray" [label]="optGroup.key">
    <md-option *ngFor="let optValue of optGroup.values" [value]="optValue.viewValue">
      {{ optValue.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
  </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0iTGJIC4nmNs3R55lFBV?p=info)